# pyspark .writeStream.format("memory") does not detect existing data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am testing out pyspark streaming with just a csv file being read from a folder.

When I use `writeStream.format("console")` the query immediately detects my csv file and outputs this in the console.

```
+-------------+
|count(userid)|
+-------------+
|          993|
+-------------+
```

But with `.writeStream.format("memory")`, only new data is detected. Before any result is shown, I need to manually copy the same source file in the source folder again.

Does anyone knows why `.writeStream.format("memory")` is not detecting the original csv file?

Also, it seems that adding watermark or not does not change any behaviour at all.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, count, from_unixtime, to_timestamp
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MusicListeningBehavior") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Define the schema for the streaming data
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StringType, LongType
schema = StructType() \
    .add("userid", StringType()) \
    .add("timestamp", LongType()) \
    .add("artistid", StringType()) \
    .add("artistname", StringType()) \
    .add("traid", StringType()) \
    .add("traname", StringType())

# Read the streaming data
tracksess = spark.readStream \
    .option("sep", "\t") \
    .schema(schema) \
    .csv("C:/GP/music-listening-behaviour-streaming/data/01_raw/stream")
tracksess.isStreaming
tracksess = tracksess.withColumn("timestamp", to_timestamp(col("timestamp")))

# first step: watermark
watermarked_df = tracksess.withWatermark('timestamp', "5 seconds")
# second step: define query and write

# tscount = watermarked_df.selectExpr("userid").distinct().agg(count("userid")).alias('usercountgp')
tscount = tracksess.selectExpr("userid").distinct().agg(count("userid")).alias('usercountgp')

query = tscount.writeStream.format("console").outputMode("complete").start()   # immediately gets the result of the one csv file in the folder
query_  = tscount.writeStream.format("memory").outputMode("complete").queryName("countusers").option("checkpointLocation", "C:/GP/music-listening-behaviour-streaming/data/01_raw/checkpoints").option('path', "C:/GP/music-listening-behaviour-streaming/data/01_raw/streamout").start() 
# the second query only works when i add data in the original readStream source folder (eg I just copypaste the source csv in the same folder)

print(query_.status)
print(query_.lastProgress)
```

Answer (score 0):

The example is a use case of one source stream and multiple sinks. In these case it is recommended to use `foreachBatch` rather than individual processing. Use can change code as following:

```
def write_to_multiple_sinks(df: DataFrame, _):
    df = df.cache()
    df.write.format("console").outputMode("complete")
    df.write.format("memory").outputMode("complete")
    
tracksess.writeStream.foreachBatch(write_to_multiple_sinks).option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint").start()
```

In this approach, your performance should be better as the source is only read once. Also, you should not see any issues with new data.